# Trying to create a pricing calculator, but nothing displays when I click calculate

Tags: javascript, html

The code was based off of a template, I am very new with Javascript, but from what I can tell everything should work just fine. However, when I test it out, nothing shows up in the results boxes and I am at a loss.

I am trying to create a pricing calculator that will come up with an estimated budget as well as the return on investment.

The actual math for the estimated budget is = (additional income) / (average house price / average commission) x 100 / 12 x 5

The math for the ROI is = Additional Income - Estimated Budget

Here's the Javascript code:

```js
<script>
  document.getElementById("loan-form").addEventListener("submit", 
  computeResults);

 function computeResults(e) {
  // UI

  const UIadditionalincome = 
  document.getElementById("additionalincome").value;
  const UIaveragecommission = 
  document.getElementById("averagecommission").value;
  const UIaveragehouseprice = 
  document.getElementById("averagehouseprice").value;

  // Calculate

  const income = parseFloat(UIadditionalincome);
  const CalculateCommission = parseFloat(UIaveragehouseprice) / 
  (UIaveragecommission);

  //Estimated Budget
  const x = Math.pow (income / CalculateCommission);
  const EstimatedBudget = (x * 100 / 12 * 5).toFixed(2);

  //ROI

  const roi = (additionalincome - totalEstimatedBudget).toFixed(2);

  //Show results

  document.getElementById("EstimatedBudget").innerHTML = "$" + 
  EstimatedBudget;

  document.getElementById("roi").innerHTML = "$" + roi;

  e.preventDefault();
   }
   </script>
```

Here's the HTML if needed:

```html
     <div class="columns">
       <div class="column is-three-quarters">
         <div class="card">
           <div class="card-content">
             <form id="loan-form">
               <div class="level">
                 <!-- Left side -->
                 <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                   <div class="level-item">
                     <p class="number">1</p>
                     Additional Income
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <!-- Right side -->
                 <div class="level-right">
                   <div class="level-item">
                     <div class="field">
                       <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                         <input class="input" id="additionalincome" 
         type="number" />
                         <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                           <i class="fa fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                         </span>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div class="level">
                 <!-- Left side -->
                 <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                   <div class="level-item">
                     <p class="number">2</p>
                     Average Commission
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <!-- Right side -->
                 <div class="level-right">
                   <div class="level-item">
                     <div class="field">
                       <div class="control has-icons-right">
                         <input class="input" id="averagecommission" 
         type="number" />
                         <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                           <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>

                         </span>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="level">
                 <!-- Left side -->
                 <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                   <div class="level-item">
                     <p class="number">3</p>
                     Average House Price
                   </div>
                 </div>

                 <!-- Right side -->
                 <div class="level-right">
                   <div class="level-item">
                     <div class="field">
                       <div class="control has-icons-left">
                         <input class="input" id="averagehouseprice" 
               type="number" />
                         <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                           <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                         </span>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div class="control">
                 <button
                   class="button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary is- 
          outlined"
                 >
                   Calculate
                 </button>
               </div>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>

 <!-- RESULTS -->
 <section class="section">
   <h1 class="title ">Calculated Results</h1>
 <div class="columns is-multiline">

<div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen">
 <div class="notification is-primary has-text">
   <p id="EstimatedBudget" class="title is-1">$</p>
   <p class="subtitle is-4">Estimated Budget</p>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen">
     <div class="notification is-info has-text">
       <p id="roi" class="title is-1">$</p>
       <p class="subtitle is-4">ROI</p>
     </div>
   </div>

 </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: You could try `<form id="loan-form" action="javascript:computeResults(null);">`, because the issue may be that the form submits, and navigates (essentially refreshes) before the javascript can execute.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd kindly like to point out that Java and JavaScript are different languages.

The problem seems to be that your calling prevent default after you've done your calculations. Just move the `e.preventDefault` to the top of the function.